# If a computer only understand 1 and 0, does that mean everything on pc including videos and musics can be made by writing in binary code?

Tags: binary, computer-science

A pc only know 1 and 0(which is a switch on or off). Then does that mean everything we have on a pc can be wrote in binary code?

**I mean, can we write binary code to create even music and videos without doing any record of any sort? Just by coding?**

With that thought in mind, I once tried to open a music in text form and copied it into a note-pad and changed its format and it worked. A few years later, I tried it again and it didn't. Any clue?

Comment: everything on your pc *is* stored as binary code, on your harddrive

Comment: @user3469811 yes, i mean we made anything on our pc by writing in binary code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sit down with a program equivalent to Notepad that writes binary files by taking your document of 0s and 1s and you can compose a playable MP3 of a classical violin concerto or a high-definition digital rendering of the Mona Lisa or even an animated GIF of the complete Lord of the Rings trilogy. All data on computers are just strings of 0 and 1.

Comment: You're on point but, I was expecting an answer with some details of how it work.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place for this type of question (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). You will have more luck [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com)